# Swift - How to make a post request

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, networking

I am trying to make a POST request using OAuthSwift but I have been stuck. Can someone point me in the right direction?

On ViewController1 we have a list of users, when you tap on a user, you get to ViewController2 which has the details for the user. If you tap a cell, you get an action sheet which you can change a user status. Once you are done, you tap 'save' and the save button should make a post request to the API.

I am lost on how to do this, here is what I have so far.

The Model for GET Request

```
struct DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer: Hashable, Codable {
    var playerId: Int
    var playerName: String?
    var numberOfStatusMissingDays: Int
    var entries: [Entry]

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(playerId)
    }

    static func == (lhs: DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer, rhs: DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer) -> Bool {
        return lhs.playerId == rhs.playerId
    }
}

struct Entry: Codable {
    var injuryIllnessId: Int
    var injuryIllnessName: String?
    var statusDate: Date
    var modifiedBy: String?
    var status: String?
    var playerStatusId: Int
    var parentEventId: Int?
}
```

The Model for the POST Request:

```
struct CreateDailyInjuryIllnessNote: Encodable {
    var teamId: UInt32
    var dailyInjuryIllnessStatus: [DailyInjuryIllnessStatus]

}

struct DailyInjuryIllnessStatus: Encodable {
    var iIeventId: UInt32
    var effectiveDate: Date
    var eventStatusId: UInt32
    var playerId: UInt32
}
```

When a user taps on the user from ViewController1, they segue to ViewController 2 where they can see the details of the user, which would be the [Entry] array from the GET Request.

View Controller2:
The user taps a cell (Entry Object) and they get an action sheet which will change the variable `status` to whatever title they selected in the action sheet (available, or unavailable).
Next, the user can tap save to send the updated status results to the RESTFUL API.
This is where I am stuck, I am not sure what to do, if you cannot help with the code can you please point me to a tutorial or the steps in pseudocode to help out?

Here is what I tried:
In ViewController2

```
private extension DailyInjuryIllnessAPI.Model.Request.CreateDailyInjuryIllnessNote {

    static func from(playerId: Int?, statusNote: DailyInjuryIllnessAPI.Model.Request.CreateDailyInjuryIllnessNote) {
        guard let playerId = playerId else { return nil }
        let teamId = statusNote.teamId
        // Extract the values and add to dailyInjuryIllnessStatusArray
        for statusValues in statusNote.dailyInjuryIllnessStatus {
            let iIeventId = statusValues.iIeventId
            let effectiveDate = statusValues.effectiveDate
            let eventStatusId = statusValues.eventStatusId
            let playerId = statusValues.playerId
        }
    }
}
```

In the model for the POST request:

```
func createDailyInjuryIllnessNote(forTeamID teamId: Int, createDailyInjuryIllnessStatus: DailyInjuryIllnessAPI.Model.Request.CreateDailyInjuryIllnessNote, completion: @escaping ((Result<DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer, API.APIError>) -> Void)) {
    guard let createDailyInjuryIllnessNoteData = try? API.jsonEncoder.encode(createDailyInjuryIllnessStatus) else {
        completion(.failure(.encoding(error: "Could not encode DailyInjuryIllnessAPi.Model.Request.CreateDailyInjuryIllnessNote: \(createDailyInjuryIllnessStatus)")))
        return
    }

    let baseURL = self.configuration.baseURL
    let endPoint = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("team/\(teamId)/daily-injury-illness-status")
    var headers: OAuthSwift.Headers = [:]
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    API.shared.httpClient.post(endPoint, headers: headers, body: createDailyInjuryIllnessNoteData) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            do {
                let note = try API.jsonDecoder.decode(DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer.self, from: response.data)
                completion(.success(note))
            } catch (let error) {
                completion(.failure(.decoding(error: error.localizedDescription)))
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.failure(.unknown(message: error.localizedDescription)))
        }
    }


}
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I have been stuck"  Stuck meaning what!?  The application will crash?  You get an error?  What's the issue?  And what is a guy named `API.shared.httpClient` where does it come from?  I have used OAuthSwift a few times.  But I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Stuck as in I have zero idea what to do to make a post request, I basically cannot figure out how to take the values in VC2 and make them into the model for the post request... and ```API.shared.httpClient``` is just the OAuthSwift Client

Comment: in the static from method I basically extract the values and put it into the format of the POST Request model, by looping ``for statusValues in statusNote.dailyInjuryIllnessStatus``` what I need to do is get that into the post request model above that is named ```CreateDailyInjuryIllnessNot```